# react native state changes after double tap.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a button and when I click on it, button changes its state. But  I have to double tap to change the state. I console logged it and on first click, it shows blank and when I click on it again, it will change its state. Below is my code:

```
class CustomButtonOne extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        buttonOne:'',
       };
      this.selectionOnPressOne = this.selectionOnPressOne.bind(this),
  }

  selectionOnPressOne = () => {
      this.setState({
        buttonOne:'ONE'
        })
        console.log(this.state.buttonOne, 'this.state.buttonOne')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={()=> this.selectionOnPressOne()}>
          <Text>Button</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
}
}

export default CustomButtonOne
```

Why is this happening? and How can I change the state with one tap? 
Any advice or comments would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setState` action is **async**, therefore the changes that you log may not be available immediately.

Try this

```
this.setState({
  buttonOne:'ONE'
}, () => console.log(this.state.buttonOne, 'this.state.buttonOne'))
```

Comment: thank you very much it works great! But I don't really understand why it works. Could you explain me what is happening? I would like to know :)

Comment: the Javascript works async, `console.log` is executed almost immediately whereas `setState` will take more time to execute. Therefore by passing `console.log` in the callback func of `setState` we can safely assume that it will be called only when the values have been changed